# Posix thread Program Multiplication - Inquire about Code blog How to check that it issues different threads

Tags: multithreading, matrix, pthreads, posix, multiplication

Found in the below link blog showing example on matrix multiplication using Posix thread, and as mentioned that each threads are holding row and column information, below is link and copied the program for reference

https://macboypro.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/matrix-multiplication-in-c-using-pthreads-on-linux/

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define M 3
#define K 2
#define N 3
#define NUM_THREADS 10

int A [M][K] = { {1,4}, {2,5}, {3,6} };
int B [K][N] = { {8,7,6}, {5,4,3} };
int C [M][N];

struct v {
   int i; /* row */
   int j; /* column */
};

void *runner(void *param); /* the thread */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   int i,j, count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
      for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
     //Assign a row and column for each thread
     struct v *data = (struct v *) malloc(sizeof(struct v));
     data->i = i;
     data->j = j;
     /* Now create the thread passing it data as a parameter */
     pthread_t tid;       //Thread ID
     pthread_attr_t attr; //Set of thread attributes
     //Get the default attributes
     pthread_attr_init(&attr);
     //Create the thread
     pthread_create(&tid,&attr,runner,data);
     //Make sure the parent waits for all thread to complete
     pthread_join(tid, NULL);
     count++;
     }
  }

   //Print out the resulting matrix
  for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
     for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
     printf("%d ", C[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
   } 
}

//The thread will begin control in this function
void *runner(void *param) {
   struct v *data = param; // the structure that holds our data
   int n, sum = 0; //the counter and sum

   //Row multiplied by column
   for(n = 0; n< K; n++){
       sum += A[data->i][n] * B[n][data->j];
   }
   //assign the sum to its coordinate
   C[data->i][data->j] = sum;

   //Exit the thread
   pthread_exit(0);
 }
```

Inquiry : is this really issuing different threads for each different Row/Column ? and how can we define that different threads are issued ?